# Rails: how to get list of required controller parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to write an RSpec test that runs a bunch of route controller actions.  The problem I'm running into is that the controllers all have different parameters that need to be supplied. Is there a way to way to see which parameters the controller is expecting?

I'm seeing a lot of stuff about how to set up strong parameters, ie.

```
params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
```

but nothing on how to tell what the controller is expecting.

Comment: I do not believe there is a built-in way to query a controller's parameter expectations/requirements.

Comment: I guess you can put `ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true if Rails.env.test?` in your `application_controller.rb`